# Adding an event to Silverlight shape in a separate class

Tags: c#, silverlight, events, silverlight-3.0

So I'm trying to create a copy of a shape once it's dropped on a canvas.
My EventHandlers are on the MainPage.xaml.cs.
Then I'm using another class to handles the dragging, dropping, etc.
Then I'm extending the shape class to create a copy and return it. Everything works, except once the rectangle is on the canvas, the events don't work. (Because they're not targeting events in the xaml.cs) How do I fix this? Thanks!

```
    // In my drag/drop class I add the control
    _cContainer.Children.Add(s.AsRectangle(_tContainer));

    // In my extension of the shape class
    public static Rectangle AsRectangle(this Shape s, Canvas c)
    {
        Rectangle r = new Rectangle() {
            Fill = s.Fill,
            Height = s.Height,
            Width = s.Width
        };
        r.MouseLeftButtonDown += new MouseButtonEventHandler(Handle_MouseDown);
        r.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(Handle_MouseMove);
        r.MouseLeftButtonUp += new MouseButtonEventHandler(Handle_MouseUp);
        Canvas.SetLeft(r, s.GetLeft() - c.Width);
        Canvas.SetTop(r, s.GetTop());
        return r;
    }
```